# Who was the first motorsport driver to perform ‘shoey’ - drinking alcohol out of a shoe, on podium?

Tags: history, international-sports, auto-racing, road-racing

*[Drinking beer out of one's own shoe is a ritual sometimes undertaken at parties and events in Australia, where it is referred to as a "shoey"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_from_shoes).*

[Jack Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Miller_(motorcycle_racer)) celebrated his maiden MotoGP victory by [drinking from his boot](http://www.townsvillebulletin.com.au/sport/proud-mum-reflects-on-jack-millers-sensational-first-motogp-triumph/news-story/9fe40688ec08eaf6437ca9443471af5c) during the podium ceremony of the Dutch Grand Prix in Assen.

[image: Jack miller]

[Daniel Ricciardo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Ricciardo) has also [performed shoeys on the podium (twice)](http://www.skysports.com/f1/news/24239/10578877/daniel-ricciardo-explains-his-shoey-podium-celebration-and-the-taste).

[image: Daniel]

[Valentino Rossi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentino_Rossi) has also [performed shoey for his 2nd place on San Marino GP](https://wwos.nine.com.au/2016/09/12/07/41/valentino-rossi-shoey-at-san-marino-gp).

[image: vale rossi]

---

So, my question is,

***Who was the first motorsport driver to perform ‘shoey’ on podium?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shoey made its way to major motorsport for the first time in 2015.

It all started with [V8 Utes driver Ryal Harris](https://www.facebook.com/RyalHarris/), who performed the very first motorsport shoey at the Perth round of the series in 2015.

[image: Ryal Harris]

From [goldcoastbulletin.com.au](http://www.goldcoastbulletin.com.au/sport/local-sport/gold-coast-v8-utes-champion-ryal-harris-the-man-behind-motorsports-global-shoey-phenomena/news-story/3e3bdfb667f776d0d73a4118e6402eef) article,

> “Yeah, I was definitely the first one to do it,”.
>
> “A couple of weeks before Perth I was on the beers with my mates and we were doing shoeys at my mate’s house and I just said, ‘If I get on the podium in Perth, I will do a shoey on the podium’.”

But When [V8 Supercar driver David Reynolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Reynolds_(racing_driver)) did a shoey after winning the second Saturday race at Darwin’s Hidden Valley later that year, it got mainstreamed (at least in Australia).

[image: Reynolds]

After this [Jack Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Miller_(motorcycle_racer)), [Daniel Ricciardo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Ricciardo) and [Valentino Rossi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentino_Rossi) have performed 'shoey' to make it a global phenomena.

References: [carthrottle.com](https://www.carthrottle.com/post/nkmklvp/), [foxsports](https://www.foxsports.com.au/motorsport/moto-gp/motogp-valentino-rossi-celebrates-second-place-at-misano-with-shoey-on-the-podium/news-story/6ccfadfe1ecd58d18f95a68dbb9f7066) and [wheelsmag.com.au](https://www.wheelsmag.com.au/features/1608/a-brief-history-of-the-shoey-in-motorsport).